# Oracle single-table constant merge with CLOB using JDBC

Tags: oracle, jdbc, merge, clob, ora-01461

As a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167471/), I need help with the following scenario:

In Oracle, given a simple data table:

```
create table data (
    id       VARCHAR2(255),
    key      VARCHAR2(255),
    value    CLOB);
```

I am using the following merge command:

```
merge into data
using (
    select
        ? id,
        ? key,
        ? value
    from
        dual
) val on (
    data.id=val.id
    and data.key=val.key
)
when matched then 
    update set data.value = val.value 
when not matched then 
    insert (id, key, value) values (val.id, val.key, val.value);
```

I am invoking the query via JDBC from a Java application.

When the "value" string is large, the above query results in the following Oracle error:

```
ORA-01461: cannot bind a LONG value for insert into a long column
```

I even set the "SetBigStringTryClob" property as documented [here](http://www.oracle.com/technology/sample_code/tech/java/codesnippet/jdbc/clob10g/handlingclobsinoraclejdbc10g.html) with the same result.

Is it possible to achieve the behavior I want given that "value" is a CLOB?

EDIT: Client environment is Java

Comment: Hello. Could you please let me know how did you solve this issue? I have very similar one described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43349999/jdbctemplate-insert-or-update-oracle-blob-using-sql-merge

Answer (score 2):

You haven't mentioned specifically in your post, but judging by the tags for the question, I'm assuming you're doing this from Java.

I've had success with code like this in a project I just finished.  This application used Unicode, so there may be simpler solutions if your problem domain is limited to a standard ASCII character set.

Are you currently using the OracleStatement.setCLOB() method?  It's a terribly awkward thing to have to do, but we couldn't get around it any other way.  You have to actually create a temporary CLOB, and then use that temporary CLOB in the setCLOB() method call.

Now, I've ripped this from a working system, and had to make a few ad-hoc adjustments, so if this doesn't appear to work in your situation, let me know and I'll go back to see if I can get a smaller working example.

This of course assumes you're using the Oracle Corp. JDBC drivers (ojdbc14.jar or ojdbc5.jar) which are found in $ORACLE_HOME/jdbc/lib

```
CLOB tempClob = CLOB.createTemporary(conn, true, CLOB.DURATION_SESSION);


// Open the temporary CLOB in readwrite mode to enable writing
tempClob.open(CLOB.MODE_READWRITE);

// Get the output stream to write
Writer tempClobWriter = tempClob.getCharacterOutputStream();

// Write the data into the temporary CLOB
tempClobWriter.write(stringData);

// Flush and close the stream
tempClobWriter.flush();
tempClobWriter.close();

// Close the temporary CLOB
tempClob.close();

myStatement.setCLOB(column.order, tempClob);
```

Regards,
Dwayne King

Comment: Ahhh...create a temporary CLOB. Interesting. Let me try it out and I'll let you know if it plays well with my "merge" statement.

Comment: Going with this solution I got an error:  `ORA-22922: nonexistent LOB value`. My case is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43349999/jdbctemplate-insert-or-update-oracle-blob-using-sql-merge. Please let me know if you can help.